# Which ST:TNG episode contains image of surprised Picard face?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

From which Star Trek The Next Generation comes this image:

[image]

And exactly in what scene it appears? What Picard is saying at the very moment, that is pictured?

Comment: Is this even a relevant question for this website? What does this have to do with sci-fi? Also, a simple Google search for "Picard meme" reveals a link to [knowyourmeme.com](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/annoyed-picard) that explains all you need to know.

Comment: this is definitely on-topic for this site, as it clearly relates to a work of science fiction. Being a simple question that shows zero research effort does not make it off-topic, it just makes it a terrible question.

Comment: @BCdotWEB There's 3 other questions of the same type just from TNG in the Related sidebar (and I remember one from TOS as well).  You can open a question on Meta about all of them if you think they shouldn't be on-topic

Comment: @Izkata Done: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6918/are-questions-asking-for-the-picture-source-of-memes-genuinely-worthwhile

Comment: I see some misunderstanding here, that should be explained. First of all, this image **is not a meme**. I intentionally stripped over "meme parts". I'm asking about episode and scene pictured here. This has nothing to do with memes. And therfore, Izkata's meta question if questions about memes are on-topic here on this site, is either off-topic or in no connection to this question.

Comment: Second of all, it seems that you haven't read my question thoroughly. I'm asking about exact words Picard is saying at pictured moment. Simple Google Graphics search _could_ reveal episode name, but not answer the question. If one is going to say, that having episode name I could look for its script, browse it thoroughly, find that particular scene and answer the question myself. And that my question shows no research, because I didn't so. Then please -- explain me, why this site exists and why we should as _any_ question. Virtually any question can be answered and can show zero own research.

Comment: @trejder "I'm asking about exact words Picard is saying at pictured moment. Simple Google Graphics search could reveal episode name, but not answer the question." I suggest you click the link in my comment and notice how it features **a video of the scene**. "Virtually any question can be answered and can show zero own research." Numerous questions here show you this is not true. As I proved, your question could be solved by **one** simple Google search, the same is not true of plenty others.

Comment: @trejder "this image is not a meme" The meme -- which is "annoyed Picard", not "surprised Picard", BTW -- uses this image and the reason you ask this question is because you're curious about its source due to its use in a meme. Which you admitted already: "I intentionally stripped over 'meme parts'".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the episode "Ménage à Troi", a Ferengi captures Riker, Deanna, and Lwaxana Troi. Picard acts like he loves Lwaxana Troi to show the Ferengi that he will do anything to get her back. He does so by reciting Shakespeare:

> "My love is a fever, longing still 
> For that which longer nurseth the disease."  
> "In faith, I do not love thee with mine eyes,  
> For they in thee a thousand errors note;  
> But 'tis my heart that loves what they despise;  
> Who in despite of view is pleas'd to dote."

The image taken comes from this moment.

(Edit: Added that he pretends to love Lwaxana Troi, not just "Troi", thanks for the comment)

Comment: You forgot to mention that this scene is even more funny than its meme.

Comment: @Trollwut Maybe he didn't mention this, because my question has nothing to do with memes?

Comment: nb Picard pretends to love Lwaxana Troi not Deanna.